# In what time $\tau$ will the particle reach the point $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, physics

A particle of mass $m$ capable of moving along the $x$-axis, is acted upon by a force $F(x) = -\frac{k}{x^3}$. At the initial time moment $t=0$, the particle is at the point $x=x_0>0$, and its velocity is $\dot{x}(0)=0$. In what time $\tau$ will the particle reach the point $x=0$?

**My attempt:**
We basically have to solve this second order nonlinear ODE $$\frac{d^{2}x}{dt^{2}}=-\frac{k}{mx^{3}}.$$
Using substitution $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$, we get $\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{k}{mx^3}$, using chain rule to rewrite $\frac{dv}{dt}=v\frac{dv}{dx}$, then separate ant integrate
$$\frac{1}{2}v^2 = \frac{k}{2mx^2} + A \implies v = \sqrt{\frac{k}{mx^2} + A}.$$
The result I got is $v = \sqrt{\frac{k}{mx^2} + A}$, where $A$ is a constant of integration. After plugging in the initial conditions we find the value of $A=-\frac{k}{2mx_0^2}$.

Next, applying the initial conditions and keeping in mind that velocity is negative due to given conditions, $$$$\begin{aligned}
&\int_0^\tau dt=-\int_{x_0}^0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac k{mx^2}-\frac k{mx_0^2}}} \\
&\tau=-\int_{x_0}^0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac k{mx^2}-\frac k{mx_0^2}}}
\end{aligned}
Are there any ways to simplify it further? I suppose we can make use of some integrals with similar form like $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}=\arcsin(\frac{x}{a})$

Comment: Now that you've got the initial conditions, Solve for $x$ in terms of $t$, by using $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$. Then check for which $t$, $x(t)=0$.

Comment: @AMC3F9 Thanks for help, so far. so I should just integrate $\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac k{mx^2}-\frac k{mx_0^2}}$? I am not sure about what limits of integration I should use here to make use of the initial conditions

Comment: $$\int_0^{\tau}dt=-\int_{x_0}^0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac k{mx^2}-\frac k{mx_0^2}}}$$(Since the particle moves from $x_0>0$ to $x=0$, the velocity is negative.)

Comment: @AndrésdeFonollosa,Use lower limits as $t=0$ and $x=x_0$ and upper limit as $t=t$ and $x=x$

Comment: @Gonçalo Many thanks, I will see if i can simplify it and maybe ask some follow up questions if you dont mind

Comment: @AndrésdeFonollosa, The integral is of form $$\int \frac{xdx}{\sqrt{1-cx^2}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time taken is given by:
$$
\tau = -\int_{x_0}^0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{mx^2}-\frac{k}{mx_0^2}}} \\
\implies \tau = -\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}x_0\int_{x_0}^0\frac{xdx}{\sqrt{x_0^2-x^2}}. \\
$$
We have that:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{a^2-x^2})=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}.
$$
Can you do the rest?

Comment: I think I got it. Could you verify, so I can make sure it's correct though? Performing $u$ substitution on the second integral with $u=x_0^2-x^2$ we get 

$\int_{0}^{x_0} \frac{du}{2\sqrt{u}} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2u^{\frac{1}{2}}\Bigg|_{0}^{x_{0}} = \sqrt{x_0^2-x^2}\Bigg|_{0}^{x_{0}} = x_0$.

Thus $\tau=-\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}x_0^2$.

Comment: $\sqrt{x_0^2-x^2}|_0^{x_0} = -x_0$, actually, @AndrésdeFonollosa

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for spotting my error.

Comment: Thanks, I got it

Answer (score 0):

From $\frac{dv}{dt} = v \frac{dv}{dx}$ we get

$$v \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{-k}{mx^3} \implies v \; dv = \frac{-k}{mx^3} \; dx.$$

Now we integrate to get

$$\frac{1}{2}v^2 = \frac{k}{2mx^2} + A \implies v = \sqrt{\frac{k}{mx^2} + A}.$$

Where did you get the $\frac{dv}{v}$ from?

Comment: Thanks for correcting my error!